# Multiple results with many-to-many relationship dapper

Tags: c#, sql, dapper

I have Items that i want to associate with 1 - many Tags

Entities:
Items
Tags
ItemTag

I want to return all the items and the associated tags for displaying in a grid. So a collection of:

```
{
ItemTitle: ''
ItemTags: [ '', '', '']
}
```

I know dapper can do multiple result sets, but not sure how i'd use that functionality here.

```
SELECT * FROM Items
SELECT * FROM Tags
SELECT * FROM ItemTag
```

Then i would need to something to bring them all together so i have a collection:

```
Items: [
{
ItemTitle: ''
ItemTags: [ '', '', '']
},
{
ItemTitle: ''
ItemTags: [ '', '', '']
}
]
```

UPDATE: I have a solution, but would like input on optimizing

```
    public List<Item> GetAll()
    {
        var sql =
            "SELECT * FROM Items;" +
            "SELECT ItemId, Tags.Title FROM ItemTag left join Tags on ItemTag.TagId = Tags.Id;";

        using (var multipleResults = this.db.QueryMultiple(sql))
        {
            var Items = multipleResults.Read<Item>().ToList();
            var tags = multipleResults.Read<Tag>().ToList();

            foreach (var Item in Items)
            {
                var ItemTags = new List<Tag>();
                foreach (var tag in tags)
                {
                    if (tag.ItemId == Item.Id)
                    {
                        ItemTags.Add(tag);
                    }
                }
                Item.Tags = ItemTags;
            }

            return Items;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You'll need a query that joins the items and tags.  Can you show the schemas for your tables.  Also would help to see the code for your entities.

Comment: Also you might want to check out this [link](http://www.tritac.com/bp-24-dapper-net-by-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what i ended up with.

```
  public List<Item> GetAll()
    {
        var sql =
            "SELECT * FROM Items;" +
            "SELECT ItemId, Tags.Title FROM ItemTag left join Tags on ItemTag.TagId = Tags.Id;";

        using (var multipleResults = this.db.QueryMultiple(sql))
        {
            var items = multipleResults.Read<Item>().ToList();
            var tags = multipleResults.Read<Tag>().ToList();

            var tagsByItemId = tags.ToLookup(t => t.ItemId);

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                item.Tags = tagsByItemId[item.Id].ToList();
            }

            return items;
        }
    }
```

Ref: [Filling List property of objects in a foreach-loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26546831/filling-list-property-of-objects-in-a-foreach-loop)